# Can you combine the JS and CSS code from different plugins into one in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which works good but has a long average loading time. According to google insights and other benchmarks, my main problem is the JS and CSS code from different plugins installed (like, 40 or so..) but mainly the JS.

Is it possible to combine all the JS into a single file without breaking the entire site and/or plugins? (I need all of them.) Is it also possible to do the same with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , You can do it by below plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, you should use another plugin for that task.

There are several that you can use and it's a matter of personal preference but here are a couple that popped from a quick search.

[Merge-Minify-Refresh](https://wordpress.org/plugins/merge-minify-refresh/)

"JS & CSS Script Optimizer" is another option.

And probably most popular one.

[W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)